# Why plus operator between two shorts returns an Int

Tags: kotlin, primitive

I'm working on a program which run on machines with limited resources. I must optimize as much as I can the memory usage.

To do so, I set Short type in parameter of different functions, but then, I noticed at one point that my variables which are Short, give an Int when I use the '+' operator.

**From Primitive.kt:**
`public operator fun plus(other: Short): Int`

Why does it return an Int rather than a short ?

Does the JVM optimize the code behind the scene ?

If i use massively the toShort function, will this slow my code ?

Comment: Note that most JVM implementations usings `shorts` instead of `int` will usually do extremely little to preserve memory or other resources, because due to alignment and other (speed) optimizations `shorts` tend to not use less memory. Also: if you think you need these kinds of micro-optimizations, then there's a good chance that the JVM is not a great platform to use.

Comment: ...either that, or you don't _really_ need them ;-)

Comment: > _Why does it return an Int rather than a short?_ Because java does the same. See https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/3refus/in_java_why_is_the_sum_of_2_shorts_an_int/